# Is PowerVault RD1000 suitable for 2 server configuration?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

We need to backup 2 Window Server 2008 R2 machines (one DC and one SQL Server) and were looking for a DELL product.

Looks like the only suitable option is PowerVault RD1000. It includes the Symantec Backup Exec QuickStart software.

Is this product suitable for a couple of server configuration (with a capacity of 250GB each)? The Symantec Backup Exec QuickStart software has to be installed on servers or is it preinstalled on the backup unit?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you speak to your Dell representative?

Comment: Yeah, that'll give you a totally unbiased answer. He can either ask a bunch of techies here that may have actually used the product or something similar, or he can ask a "sweet bro" salesman. I think it's a fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Are RDX removable disks a good replacement for LTO tape?](https://serverfault.com/questions/313102/are-rdx-removable-disks-appropriate-replacements-for-lto-tapes) for information about the technology.

Yes, the drive would be suitable for your application.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any LTO solution with comparable prices?

Comment: No. At the low-end, you can find an LTO-2 solution with 400B capacity for $1500, plus tapes. For instance, HP has a bundle for ~$1500US (#AG736A) that includes an external tape drive and a SAS HBA to connect it to a server.

Comment: Thanks so much again, I would cost more that the two server themselves ;).

Answer (score 0):

The Backup Exec QuickStart software has to be installed on each server you're planning to back up.

You should be aware that the QuickStart version of Backup Exec is a very basic product. It will only backup a single server. There is no ability to install additional agents. So, for example, you can't use it to backup other servers over the network. You also won't be able to install the BUE agents for backing up SQL Server and Exchange; it will only do a basic flat-file backup.